# What is the exact purpose of the Android Notification Category? Specifically CATEGORY_WORKOUT?

Tags: android, xamarin

Android Api level 31 introduces 2 new Categories CATEGORY_WORKOUT, CATEGORY_STOPWATCH. I tried to find a detailed information about those but nothing detailed is documented.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification

Is there any advantage of using those for a workout or stopwatch application? earlier I was using Category Progress which is claimed to keep as long running task. I suppose that Android gives it priority.

Comment: It seems that just add two const to the notificaton category which is set by the developer. Maybe just to supplement the notification type and make the developer have more choice when create a notification.

Answer (score 0):

These categories are for ongoing notifications either on your phone or on a WearOS device.

The category will help the OS prioritize the importance of the notification.

There is an example of the usage in this Edge Wear OS ongoing activity walkthrough: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/ongoing-activity